# Insert bullet and newline into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a way, using gridview let users to input newlines and bullets in a cell?
Since there's no Bullet key on the keyboard, probably I can assign shortcut?

Another way I'm thinking is allowing users to insert asteriks, but when I'm going to build report, I'm going to replace asteriks with asci bullet.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

using asp.net, gridview, sql server 2008 r2

Comment: You can use a custom editor that have new lines and bullets when you edit a gridview line.

Comment: What is a custom editor? I guess it will slow down a process significantly

Comment: Custom html editor, like fckeditor, like tinyeditor... look on internet and select one, then make a custom field on your grid view with that editor. I do not think that slow down anything, of cource this is also depents from how many editors you going to include, I beline only one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Textbox Editor, which will give you give you what you are looking. User can easily create and edit HTML content.

Have a look into http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

and very good this one http://ckeditor.com/demo